# Copy rows from the same table and update with different ID column and another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want copy the table and put different value on column Type= B and auto_increment id
[image]

Comment: Is ID column identity?

Comment: instead of adding an image of your table, add T-SQL `CREATE TABLE` scripts, etc, to form an example that others can use to provide an accurate answer...  See [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Id column is identity, you can achieve with below script:

```
insert into your_table ([parent_id], [order], [section], [name], [url], [type])
select [parent_id], [order], [section], [name], [url], 'B'
from your_table
where [type] = 'A'
```

If Id is not identity, use below logic:

```
-- find current max
declare @max int = (select max(ID) from your_table)

-- declare table var
declare @table table ([Id] int identity(1,1), [parent_id] nvarchar(50), [order] int, [section] nvarchar(50), [name] nvarchar(50), [url] nvarchar(50), [type] nvarchar(50))

-- insert values into this table
insert into @table
select [parent_id], 
    [order], 
    [section], 
    [name], 
    [url], 
    'B'
from your_table
where [type] = 'A'

-- then insert values from teble variable to your table
insert into your_table ([Id],[parent_id], [order], [section], [name], [url], [type])
select @max + [Id],
    [parent_id], 
    [order], 
    [section], 
    [name], 
    [url], 
    [type]
from @table
```

Comment: @AshekMahmud, is Mahbub Riyad you different login or what? Do not understand your request, there is already an answer provided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261381/how-to-copy-treeviews-rows-from-the-same-table-and-update-with-different-id-col

Comment: yeah its my friend account he needs help, i was trying to find out the answer to help him

Comment: @AshekMahmud, have added some solution to other question

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert select  declaring the column you want insert and select the corresponding column from the same table  and assigning a literal 'B'  for the column type

```
insert into menu (  parent_id, order section, name, url, type)
select parent_id, order section, name, url, 'B'
from menu 
where type ='A'
```