# how to copy TreeView's rows from the same table and update with different ID column and copy the parent_id

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I want copy the table and put different value on column Type= B and auto_increment id and copy the parent id

**Table = Menu**

```
Id | parent_id | order | section | name | url | type

100 | NULL | 7 | web | Tasks | ~/en/Tasks | A

102 | 100 | 1 | web | Pages | ~/en/Pages | A

103 | 100 | 4 | web | Category | ~/en/Category | A

104 | NULL | 3 | web | DLM | ~/en/DLM | A

105 | 104 | 6 | web | ONS | ~/en/ONS | A

106 | 104 | 2 | web | HBO | ~/en/HBO | A

107 | NULL | 7 | web | Tasks | ~/en/Tasks | B

108 | 107 | 1 | web | Pages | ~/en/Pages | B

109 | 107 | 4 | web | Category | ~/en/Category | B

110 | NULL | 3 | web | DLM | ~/en/DLM | B

111 | 110 | 6 | web | ONS | ~/en/ONS | B

112 | 110 | 2 | web | HBO | ~/en/HBO | B
```

Comment: mysql or (MS)sql-server?

Comment: its sql-server, thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this is one of those times you are going to be forced to do this RBAR (row by agonizing row). A cursor is the likely choice here.

Comment: Here is how you might approach this.  Create a new table, setting the identity value to a known starting value.  Then insert all of the rows from the "A" table to "B".  Now that you have new ids, you can create a mapping table by joining table A to table B using name (assuming it's unique).  Then update parent ID's by using the mapping table you just created.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the most efficient, but it gets the job done.  It assumes that name is unique.  I left out columns unnecessary to the example. Also, you can't put a variable into the identity clause, so that needs to be wrapped in an EXEC

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'paths', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE paths
IF OBJECT_ID (N'new_paths', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE new_paths

CREATE TABLE paths (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    name NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO dbo.paths
(id,parent_id,name)
VALUES
(100, NULL, 'Tasks'),
(102, 100, 'Pages'),
(103, 100, 'Category'),
(104, NULL, 'DLM'),
(105, 104, 'ONS'),
(106, 104, 'HBO')

DECLARE @start_value INT 
SET @start_value = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM paths) + 1

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
SET @sql = N'
CREATE TABLE new_paths (
    id INT IDENTITY(' + CAST(@start_value AS nvarchar) + ',1),
    parent_id INT,
    name NVARCHAR(20)
)
'
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @sql

INSERT INTO new_paths (parent_id,name)
SELECT Parent_id, name FROM dbo.paths

;WITH mappings AS (
SELECT n.*, p.id AS old_id
FROM new_paths n
INNER JOIN paths p
ON p.name = n.name
)

UPDATE n
SET n.parent_id = m.id
FROM new_paths n
INNER JOIN mappings m
ON m.old_id = n.parent_id

--SELECT * FROM new_paths
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below approach to resolve an issue, ask questions in the comments if something is unclear, I have added some explanation in code comments

**EDITED, to manage GUID (as per comment)**

```
-- declare table var
declare @table table ([Increment] int identity(1,1), Id uniqueidentifier, [parent_id] nvarchar(50), [order] int, [section] nvarchar(50), [name] nvarchar(50), [url] nvarchar(50), [type] nvarchar(50))

-- insert values into this table
insert into @table
select [Id],
    [parent_id], 
    [order], 
    [section], 
    [name], 
    [url], 
    'B'
from your_table
where [type] = 'A'

-- loop your temp table
declare @max_temp int = (select max(Increment) from @table)
declare @curr int = 1
declare @parent_value uniqueidentifier = null

while (@curr <= @max_temp)
begin
    -- do diffrent inserts depend on parent_id value
    if (select parent_id from @table) = null
    begin
        -- set below var, it will be used in next insert where parent_id is not null
        set @parent_value = (select Id from @table where Increment = @curr)

        insert into your_table ([parent_id], [order], [section], [name], [url], [type])
        select 
            [parent_id], 
            [order], 
            [section], 
            [name], 
            [url], 
            [type]
        from @table 
        where Id = @curr
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into your_table ([parent_id], [order], [section], [name], [url], [type])
        select 
            isnull(@parent_value, [parent_id]), 
            [order], 
            [section], 
            [name], 
            [url], 
            [type]
        from @table 
        where Id = @curr
    end

    -- update current
    set @curr = @curr + 1
end
```

Comment: if my id is Guid id, what do i do?

Comment: @MahbubRiyad, done, check now. Remember to upvote if helpful, accept is answer resolved your issue.